# Why isn't the array being passed by reference?

Tags: c++

Why is it that x prints out 1,2,3,4 instead of 4,3,2,1. When i print input[0] it says 4. Shouldn't the array have been passed by reference? So I can use x to refer to input which was originally x? This is C++ by the way.
This is not a duplicate of the other question.  If I print out the array in rev listo, it prints correctly. The issue is in terms of the array being callable in the main function.

```
using namespace std;

void rev_listo(int input[], int num)
{
    int end_list[num];

    for (int x = 0; x<num; x++) {
        end_list[x]=input[num-x-1];
        // cout<<end_list[x]<<endl;
    }
    // std::cout<<input<<std::endl;

    input=end_list;
    cout<<input[0]<<endl;
}

int main() {
    int x [4];
    x[0]=1;
    x[1]=2;
    x[2]=3;
    x[3]=4;

    rev_listo(x,  4);

    for(int y = 0; y<4; y++) {
        std::cout<<x[y]<<std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You can't pass arrays in C. `int (input)[]` actually makes `input` a pointer.

Comment: `int end_list[num];` is not allowed in C++.  Variable-length arrays are a C thing.

Comment: To use `x` for the loop counter in `rev_listo()` is confusing. May I suggest `i`? Also, despite what a few poor textbooks say, `using namespace std;` dumps the namespace. You should not do that.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying that the print statement inside the loop in rev_listo() prints wrong, and the loop in main prints correctly?

Comment: @anatolyg if I were to print out the array in the rev listo function, it will print it out reversed.

Comment: main prints out 1 2 3 4, rev listo prints out 4 3 2 1 @Chipster

Comment: @AxtonTheGreat So what you're really asking is why doesn't the array get reversed in main?

Comment: Actually this is a good example to understand more of the difference between pointer and not.

Comment: @AxtonTheGreat `int end_list[num];` -- No need to read past this line.  The compiler can do anything it wants to make this "work", since it is not C++.  Thus this line `input=end_list;` is just as fake as `int end_list[num];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internally, When you do `void rev_listo(int input[], int num)`, a pointer pointing to first element of the array is passed (just to avoid copying of array).

Like this:

```
void rev_listo(int *input /* = &(arr[0])*/, int num)
```

Please note that the `input` pointer itself is copied by value, not by reference.
So, When you do this, address of first element of `end_list` is copied to `input` pointer.:

```
input=end_list;
```

When the function ends, the pointer `input` dies.

```
void rev_listo(int input[], int num)
{

    int end_list[num];

    for(int x = 0; x<num; x++){
       end_list[x]=input[num-x-1];
    //cout<<end_list[x]<<endl;
    }
   // std::cout<<input<<std::endl;

    input=end_list;
   cout<<input[0]<<endl;
} // input pointer dies here. So does num.
```

Instead of just assigning the pointer like this: `input=end_list;` , you should copy the array manually. Like this:

```
for(int x = 0; x<num; x++){
   input[x] = end_list[x];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Shouldn't the array have been passed by reference?

No. An argument will be a reference only if the type of the argument is a reference type. A reference to type `T` is declared like this: `T&`. You'll find that there is no `&` in your argument declaration. You've declared the argument to be a pointer to an integer.

Although the argument declaration looks like an array (with the size missing), it isn't actually an array. Arguments cannot have an array type. Arguments that are declared to be arrays are *adjusted* to be a pointer to an element of such array. Your function declaration is equivalent to `void rev_listo(int *input, int num)`.

> Why is it that x prints out 1,2,3,4

Because the function doesn't modify the array elements pointed by the argument `input`. It only modifies a local array `end_list`, and the local pointer `input`.

---

P.S. The declaration `int end_list[num];` is ill-formed in C++ because `num` is not a compile time constant.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid rewriting on the legitimately occupied memory locations; iterate over only half of the size. E.g.

```
void revvings(int *d, int size) {
    int dh = (int)size/2;
       for(int i=0; i<dh; ++i) {
       int df = d[i];
       int dl = d[size-1-i];
       d[i]        = dl;
       d[size-1-i] = df;
    }
}

#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    int size = 7;
    int *d = new int[size];
    d[0] = 0; d[1] = 1; d[2] = 2; d[3] = 3; d[4] = 4; d[5] = 5; d[6] = 6;
    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i) printf("{%d} ", d[i]);
    puts("");    
    revvings(d, size);
    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i) printf("{%d} ", d[i]);
    puts("");




    return 0;
}
```